# Blocking screen only on horizontal scrolling of Recycler-View with View-Pager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I want to block the view-pager swiping only when the recycler-view is scrolling horizontally (right-left). I applied the .addOnItemTouchListener and property MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN but the problem with this property is that it also blocks the up and downward movement of the screen on the recycler-view. I just want to block the screen while scrolling recycler-view horizontally not vertically.

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction();
               
                switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        rv.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                        break;
                
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(@NonNull RecyclerView view, @NonNull MotionEvent event) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Does the ViewPager start dragging immediately, or only after the RecyclerView reaches the end of the list and the touch event passes up to its' parents (and thus the ViewPager?)

Comment: Without setting the property "ACTION_DOWN" it's random, sometimes recycler-view scrolls and sometimes it's the view-pager that swipes first. And with property, it's only the recycler-view which takes effect no movement of the screen, not even vertically.
And with the property view-pager doesn't take effect even recycler-view reaches the endpoint.

Comment: @Michiel my query is that I want to keep the screen vertical movement enabled all the time, even while interacting with the recycler-view.

Comment: The app just started, the screen is initialized and has not been touched yet. There is a ViewPager with 2 fragments, the left fragment is showing. This fragment contains a RecyclerView that can scroll horizontally. The first RecyclerView is showing, the last is not. The user put its' finger in the middle of the RecyclerView and moves his finger to the left. What behaviour do you want to see?